# Python os.system connect to pool

Tags: python, subprocess, pool, os.system

I am trying to achieve a unified environment. For example:

```
os.system('''
a = "123"
b = "456"
''')
os.system('''
echo $a
echo $b
''')
```

I need see: 123, 456, but os.system close pool and value of variables a, b are not defined. How can I connect to 1 pool?

Comment: `a = "123"` is going to fail already. Try it on the shell!

Comment: what pool are you talking about?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why can't you just merge them into one call/one process spawned (e.g. with `subprocess.Popen`)?

Comment: Because I want to execute this code in the console then do something else programmatically and then continue working with the console

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga because there = should be merged with a variable (a='123' or a=123), but I cite the code above in python, so it doesn't matter